# ASP.NET MVC doesn't pass on id when I select it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm making a basic webshop to learn myself how to program in C#. I'm a beginner and I learn everything with the help of E-books, youtube and ofcourse Stackoverflow. Now I arrived at a problem that I can't solve by myself so I really need the help of you guys.

The problem is the following.. When I press on the button 'webshop' in the menu I go to a page that lists all my products with name, picture, price, etc etc and an 'ADD TO CART' button. When i press this button I should go to my shopping cart and I should see the selected product with the chosen quantity (at this moment it's default 1) and the price of the product with the total price of all the products. When i press the button I go to my cart but this cart remains empty. The id that's send to my AddToCart method in de CartController is null... how do I fix this? You can look at the relevant code below.

**RouteConfig**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Webshop
{
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
}
```

**ProductSummary (partial view that has the AddToCart button)**

```
@model Webshop.Models.Entiteiten.Product

<div class="col-md-4">
    @if (@Model.ImageData != null)
        {
    <div class="pull-left" style="margin-right: 10px">
        <img class="img-thumbnail" width="75" height="75"
             src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Product",new { @Model.ProductID })" />
    </div>
}
<h3>@Model.Name</h3>
@Model.Description
<h4>@Model.Price.ToString("c")</h4>
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart"))
        {
    <div class="pull-right">
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProductID)
        @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to cart" />
    </div>
}
```

**Cart model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Webshop.Models.Entiteiten
{
    public class Cart
{
    private List<CartLine> lineCollection = new List<CartLine>();

    public void AddItem(Product product, int quantity)
    {
        CartLine line = lineCollection
        .Where(p => p.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID)
        .FirstOrDefault();
        if (line == null)
        {
            lineCollection.Add(new CartLine
            {
                Product = product,
                Quantity = quantity
            });
        }
        else {
            line.Quantity += quantity;
        }
    }
    public void RemoveLine(Product product)
    {
        lineCollection.RemoveAll(l => l.Product.ProductID ==
        product.ProductID);
    }
    public decimal ComputeTotalValue()
    {
        return lineCollection.Sum(e => e.Product.Price * e.Quantity);
    }
    public void Clear()
    {
        lineCollection.Clear();
    }
    public IEnumerable<CartLine> Lines
    {
        get { return lineCollection; }
    }
}
public class CartLine
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
}
```

**CartController**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Webshop.DB.Abstract;
using Webshop.Models.Entiteiten;
using Webshop.Models;

namespace Webshop.Controllers
{
public class CartController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository repository;
    public CartController(IProductRepository repo)
    {
        repository = repo;
    }

    public ViewResult Index(string returnUrl)
    {
        return View(new CartIndexViewModel
        {
            Cart = GetCart(),
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl
        });
    }

    public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(int? id, string returnUrl)
    {
        Product product = repository.Products
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == id);
        if (product != null)
        {
            GetCart().AddItem(product, 1);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
    }

    public RedirectToRouteResult RemoveFromCart(int? id, string returnUrl)
    {
        Product product = repository.Products
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == id);
        if (product != null)
        {
            GetCart().RemoveLine(product);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
    }

    private Cart GetCart()
    {
        Cart cart = (Cart)Session["Cart"];
        if (cart == null)
        {
            cart = new Cart();
            Session["Cart"] = cart;
        }
        return cart;
    }
}
}
```

CartIndexViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Webshop.Models.Entiteiten;

namespace Webshop.Models
{
    public class CartIndexViewModel
    {
        public Cart Cart { get; set; }
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because the value you are posting doesn't match the parameter name that your Controller Action is expecting.If you take a look at your existing form, you'll see that you post a value named `ProductID` to your `Cart/AddToCart` controller action :

```
<!-- This will post a value named "ProductID" to Cart/AddToCart -->
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProductID)
```

However, if you take a look at the action itself, it's expecting a parameter named `id` instead :

```
public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(int? id, string returnUrl)
{
    // Omitted for brevity
}
```

The reason that this is occurring is that the `HiddenFor()` helper is going to create an element with a `name` attribute that corresponds to the name of the property that was passed in :

```
<input id='ProductID' name='ProductID' type='hidden' value='{your-product-id}' />
```

When this gets posted, your `AddToCart` controller action doesn't see a parameter called `ProductID`, so it doesn't know how to map it (as just `id` is there).

**Possible Resolutions**

There are a few possilbe ways that you could resolve this, depending on your preferences.

**Rename your AddToCart parameter name from `id` to `ProductID`**

```
public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(int? ProductID, string returnUrl)
{
     // Omitted for brevity
}
```

**Rename the property in your form from `ProductID` to `id` to match your action**

```
@Html.Hidden("id", Model.ProductID)
```

Comment: I did the second solution and it works perfectly. Thank you very much, you can't believe how many hours I was stuck on this problem. Thanks again!